# How to make dropdown's list selected value disabled in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a question here. I need to make my selected value disabled in `Yii2`

Here is my `dropDownlist` :

```
<?= Html::dropDownList(
    'calculation-type',
    Employee::DISABLED, [
        'disabled' => true,
    ]
    $calculationTypeList, [
      'id' => 'calculation-type',
    ]);
```

I need to make that value `Employee::DISABLED` selected and disabled, but now the `'diabled' => true` doesn't work. Could someone explain me why and how it should look? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail) you should do it like that:

```
<?= Html::dropDownList(
    'calculation-type',
    Employee::DISABLED,
    $calculationTypeList,
    [
        'id' => 'calculation-type',
        'options' => [
            Employee::DISABLED => ['disabled' => true]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you also tell me maybe is it possible to make the `disabled` value disabled not just when i click a `dropDownlist`, but also when i load the page? For example when I load the page, I don't need to click the `dropDownlist` to see if it's disabled, `seleced value` instantly turns `gray` without clicking a `dropDownlist`? I hope you understand

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. This code should make the option disabled no matter if you click it or not. This might be a case of browser not rendering it properly on load.

Comment: I uploaded the example: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/1350/EyU2ds.png. As you can see `selected value` is not disabled (`it's not gray`) when I'm not clicking on a `dropDownList`. I hope you understand now

Comment: Hmm, based on how browsers work I'm not sure if this is what you want - this value most probably is sent on form submit anyway.